# How to remove packages checks when updating with dnf

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I installed some packages and removed them, but they still do some checks when I try updating the system with `sudo dnf update` on fedora. How can I remove them ?

I tried to check the **/etc/dnf/dnf.conf** file but it doesn't contain anything relating to the packages that are causing the checks

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: You could add some information about what checks you are talking about, or possibly what packages you are talking about.  Information about how you are installing/removing packages could also help.  The behavior you describe in your question is not how I have experienced `dnf` to work: `dnf` does not run any checks from packages that are not currently installed.  Maybe the issue is that you did not actually remove the packages in question?